# Need help finding the best way to query Apigee or Google Cloud (GCP) for API traffic and details

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, apigee

I am struggling to find an effective way of querying all the API traffic from apigee outside of the awful custom reports interface. I have 13 different orgs in each dev enviroment that i need to query. looking for detailed information like traffic per proxy, traffic per developer, traffic per app, traffic per external and internal.
Anyone know of a solution?

I have used the analyze tab in apigee and have not been able to find effective ways of pulling reports outside of 14 day windows or for custom reports a very manual process of selecting dates and all of these are org specific. Pulling this data takes hours.

Comment: The other option(if possible) is to post logs to a log aggregator such as Splunk, Loggly, Elasticsearch, etc., and build reports using that. What you post is under your control, so you can easily include the proxy details, consumer/app details etc., in the logs. This way there is no limit on the number of days you can query report for.